# the read function in my socket API does not work and lags

Tags: java, serversocket

I made a single mode chess game that is has no bugs as far as i know and i started the multiplayer mode.
After i connect the two players successfully, one window (the server player window) works but the opponent window lags the specific line `"movement = opponentPlayer.in.readLine();"`, it shows no error or anything at all, in fact it stops the window from responding without showing any progress as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94sr8.png)

Code:

```
private void receiveMovement() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("I Entered receiveMovement");
        String movement = null;
        if (serverPlayer != null) {
            System.out.println("I Entered serverPlayer");
            movement = serverPlayer.in.readLine();
            board.whiteTurn = movement.charAt(4) == 1;
        } else if (opponentPlayer != null) {
            System.out.println("I Entered opponentPlayer");
            movement = opponentPlayer.in.readLine();
            board.whiteTurn = movement.charAt(4) == 1;
        }
        System.out.println(movement);
//        int yAxis1 = movement.charAt(0) -'a';
//        int yAxis2 = movement.charAt(2) -'a';
//        System.out.println(yAxis1);
//        System.out.println(yAxis2);
//        Coordinate sourceCoordinate = new Coordinate(movement.charAt(1), yAxis1); //not sure of the order
//        Coordinate destinationCoordinate = new Coordinate(movement.charAt(3), yAxis2);
        assert movement != null;
        Coordinate sourceCoordinate = new Coordinate(movement.charAt(1), movement.charAt(0) - 'a');
        Coordinate destinationCoordinate = new Coordinate(movement.charAt(3), movement.charAt(2) - 'a');
        sourceTile = board.getTile(sourceCoordinate);
        destinationTile = board.getTile(destinationCoordinate);
    }
```

the system messages:

```
I Entered play Successfully
I Entered opponent play, i'm stuck
I Entered receiveMovement
I Entered opponentPlayer

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` method in input streams is a blocking call (like explained [in the api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read())). Therefore your programm will always wait for input as soon as it reaches the `readLine()` method. If this method is called from a gui it will stop the gui and it freezes.

A solution would be to execute your code in another [thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) so the main thread doesn't get blocked. After receiving the data in the thread you can inform the gui or any other class that there is a new move (or any other data) available.

Comment: sorry for the extreme late reply, i had some issues, it worked as expected; only one matter is remaining, this readLine(); doesn't receive anything for no reason that i know of, any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you are sending without a newline `\n` at the end of your send string? Becaus `readLine` will wait for a  line to end before reading and returning, even if there already is some text in the input stream.